# How to create a road like the one in the picture in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I was trying to create a road network. But no luck yet.

The bus-lane and the car-lane should have different colors.

Comment: Forgot to mention the bus-lane and the car-lane should have different color. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! A good question is made up of what you want the result to be (what you have) and what you have tried so far (what you don't have), so please add that. This makes it easier for us to help you adjust and improve your code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @JānisLazovskis Don't you mean that the other way around?

Answer (score 7):

Find some car and bus icons or pictures that you like. And include them as nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[green!70] (0,0) rectangle (10,2);
\fill[red!70] (0,0) rectangle (10,-2);
\draw[line width=1mm, dashed] (0,0)--(10,0);
\draw[line width=1mm] (0,2)--(10,2);
\draw[line width=1mm] (0,-2)--(10,-2);

\draw[-LaTeX, line width=.5mm] (.5,-1) --++(3,0) node[pos=.2, above] {Car lane};
\draw[-LaTeX, line width=.5mm, red] (.5,1)  --++(3,0) node[pos=.2, above] {Bus lane};

\node at (5,1) {\reflectbox{\includegraphics[height=8mm]{bus-symbol-tobefree}}};
\node at (8,1) {\reflectbox{\includegraphics[height=8mm]{bus-symbol-tobefree}}};

\node at (5,-1) {\includegraphics[height=5mm]{carsymbol3-crop}};
\node at (6,-.35) {\includegraphics[height=5mm]{carsymbol3-crop}};
\node at (7,-1.25) {\includegraphics[height=5mm]{carsymbol3-crop}};
\node at (8,-0.7) {\includegraphics[height=5mm]{carsymbol3-crop}};
\node at (9,-1.4) {\includegraphics[height=5mm]{carsymbol3-crop}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- Bus icon from: https://openclipart.org/detail/218241/bus-symbol-pictogram.
- Car icon from: https://openclipart.org/detail/267551/car-icon-3

Answer (score 3):

> *Note that I think I ought not answer do-it-for-mes, but sometimes do anyhow. When I do, I do so on a strictly as-is basis. I do it for me, will not be sympathetic to requests for fine-tuning or explanations unless I like them and do not consider myself strictly limited to any requirements, desiderata or constraints given in the question. If it is useful, that's a lucky bonus; if not, tough.*
>
> ## *Caveat emptor*

Cars are dangerous, polluting, planet- and soul-destroying things. Support is provided for public transport only.

[image: buses/trams]

```
\begin{filecontents}{tikzlibrarytrambws.code.tex}
\ProvidesFile{tikzlibrarytrambws.code.tex}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\colorlet{lliwytram}{red!75!black}
\colorlet{lliwffenestri}{gray!75!blue}
\colorlet{lliwolwynion}{gray!75}
\tikzset{
  lliw y tram/.code={
        \colorlet{lliwytram}{#1}
  },
  lliw ffenestri/.code={
        \colorlet{lliwffenestri}{#1}
  },
  lliw olwynion/.code={
        \colorlet{lliwolwynion}{#1}
  },
  olwyn/.style={circle, draw, line width=#1*.8pt, minimum width=#1*5pt, inner sep=0pt, fill=lliwolwynion},
  pics/tram/.style={
        code={
          \path [draw, line width=#1*.8pt]
          coordinate (tram) ++(-.2*#1,#1*2.75pt) node (w1) [olwyn=#1] {}
                  ++(#1*.425,0) node (w2) [olwyn=#1] {}
                  ++(#1*.425,0) node (w3) [olwyn=#1] {};
          \path [draw, fill, line width=#1*.4pt]
                (w1) circle (#1*1pt)
                (w2) circle (#1*1pt)
                (w3) circle (#1*1pt);
          \path [draw, left color=lliwytram, right color=lliwytram!20, line width=#1*.4pt]
                (tram) ++(-.4*#1,#1*1.5pt) coordinate (t1) |- ++(#1*1.25,#1*.35) coordinate (t2) |- (w3.south east -| w3.east) |- (w3.west) |- (w2.south east -| w2.east) |- (w2.west) |- (w1.south east -| w1.east) |- (w1.west) -- (w1.south west -| w1.west) -| cycle
                (t1 -| t2) ++(-.05*#1pt,#1*4pt) coordinate (t3) |- ++(-.175*#1,#1*.175) coordinate (t4) |- cycle
                (t3 -| t4) ++(-.5*#1pt,0) |- ++(-.25*#1,.175*#1) coordinate (t5) |- cycle
                (t3 -| t5) ++(-.5*#1pt,0) |- ++(-.25*#1,.175*#1) coordinate (t6) |- cycle
                (t3 -| t6) ++(-.5*#1pt,0) |- ++(-.25*#1,.175*#1) coordinate (t7) |- cycle
                (t3 -| t7) ++(-.5*#1pt,0) |- ++(-.25*#1,.175*#1) coordinate (t8) |- cycle;
          \scoped [on background layer] \fill [left color=lliwffenestri!50, right color=lliwffenestri!10] (t3) rectangle (t8);
        }
  }
}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trambws,fit,arrows.meta,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
  \path (0,0) node (bl) [anchor=south east, text=magenta] {Bus lane} (2,0) [lliw ffenestri=gray!75!red, lliw olwynion=orange] pic {tram=1} ++(2,0) [lliw y tram=blue!50!cyan, lliw ffenestri=gray!75!blue, lliw olwynion=blue] pic {tram=1}++(2,0) [lliw y tram=green!75!black, lliw ffenestri=green!25!gray!75, lliw olwynion=magenta] pic {tram=1};
  \draw [-Stealth, thick, magenta] (bl) -- +(2,0);
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node (g) [top color=green!50!black, bottom color=green!50!black, middle color=green!25, fit=(current bounding box.north west) (current bounding box.south east)] {};
    \path (current bounding box.north west) coordinate (tl) (current bounding box.south east) coordinate (mr) (tl |- mr) coordinate (ml) (tl -| mr) coordinate (tr);
    \shade [top color=red!50!black, bottom color=red!50!black, middle color=red!25] ($2*(ml)-(tl)$) coordinate (bl) rectangle (mr);
  \end{scope}
  \draw [double=black, double distance=3pt, draw=white] (tl) -- (tr) (bl) -- (bl -| mr) ;
  \draw [line width=1.5pt, dashed, preaction={line width=1.5pt, draw=white}] (ml) -- (mr);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```